# How to define a product's display order in a smart collection with sort-order=manual, via API?

Tags: api, shopify

I created a smart collection and changed the sort-order property to "manual" so I can define the products that should appear first when this collection is rendered.  Next I need to change some products via the API to make them appear first (higher priority).  What product property do I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection’s entries are called collects (I know, it’s weird), and that’s where Shopify stores the entry’s position in the collection.

Check out the "position" field on the [Collect resource](http://api.shopify.com/collect.html)

Comment: I thought collects only applies to Custom Collections?

Comment: Collects should still exist even for smart collections; we just rebuild them whenever the conditions change.

Comment: If they're rebuilt, wouldn't I lose the changes I made?

Comment: “Rebuild” was probably the wrong word to use here. More like “generate”.

Comment: As long as you set the position correctly and the sort order is set to manual, you should be fine.

Comment: are you sure about this?  I finally got to implement this solution and so far the API has denied every attempt I made to create, update or even delete a collect belonging to a smart collection.  I can GET a list of collects just fine, but POST, PUT and DELETE fail immediately with errors such as "Cannot destroy a Collect belonging to a SmartCollection" or "Cannot create a Collect belonging to a SmartCollection".